# How to create a layout in android like 9gag

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout, android-xml

How do i create a layout like 9gag? 
I have used the hierachery viewer to see the layout:

[9gag view hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGpyA.png)

It seems like there are linearlayouts in the listview that contain each block. How is that even possibly? Should i create a custom array adapter that serves linearlayouts?

I searched the web but couldnt find one example. Also i tried creating the Linearlayout as children of the listview but that resulted in an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list contains list items that can use any layout. See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Comment: Cool thanks. Should have read it better! Followed this [link](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429) tutorial and then edited it to my needs